# Prevent element from inherit CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i'd like to know if there's a way to prevent a child element from inherit it's parent css, for example i have something like:

```
<div class="MenuSections>
<figure class="MenuIcon">
<img.../>
<figcaption class="MenuCaption">
</figure>
</div>
```

Then i use JQuery to change the Section and caption color when Section is clicked:

```
$(this).find("div").css("background-color", "white");
$(this).find(".MenuCaption").css("color", "Darkgreen");
```

But as my img is transparent it won't be visible on a white background.

I know you can override css properties on child elements but obviously this won't work on an img element, so what can i do?

**Notes:**

- BG colors are not negotiable
- position: absolute can't be used
- Img Must be transparent, so i can't toggle between imgs on JQuery

Comment: Why can't you use absolute position?

Comment: The img isn't _inheriting_ the background colour. It is just transparent. If you want a white image to be visible on a white element, set a background colour on the img tag.

Comment: After re-reading your question, I actually have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: Before you change the color of your `div` with jQuery, where is it deriving its color from before that and is that fixed by the CSS of a container? Your "BG colors are not negotiable" statement may be troublesome if it means you're not allowed to control them the way that may be necessary.

Comment: Does your stylesheet have background specified for figure elements or .MenuIcon ?  Otherwise, what color do you expect them to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use CSS selectors within Jquery.

So in your Jquery code you could do something like ..

```
$(this).find("div *:not(<input element not to be selected>)).css("background-color", "white");
```

The * declares all elements... so all elements that are not what you selected.

You can find more information on sleectors here : https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/